# Which one faster run stored procedure from Crystal Report rpt or from code in .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I plan to create a system that shows report using Crystal Reports, and I want to know which one faster, to run stored procedures from Crystal Reports `.rpt`, or from code that send records to `.rpt`?

Why you can assume for this performance? Need your assistance, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stored procedure to pull data from database.

And then, programmatically, set this data as `DataSource` of the report.

As you know that, stored procedure have already saved at database so it will give you data more faster than normal query.

Comment: i mean crystal report .rpt also have data source option to use from store procedure, i just send parameter input, call that rpt path in code and it will generate data automatic.

and i compare with code that call store procedure, then send the records to crystal report data source.

Comment: performance will be same in both case. But if you call Store Procedure programmaticaly then it will be more handy to you.

Comment: `As you know that, store procedure have already executed at database so it will give you data more faster than normal query` - huh?  All queries execute on the database.  The primary difference is that a SP is a saved SQL object and most likely will have a better execution plan from the database engine.  It is not a pre-fired query with results just sitting around (how would it handle parameters in this instance).  I agree that SP are generally faster than a query sent from code, but not because of the reason you specified.

Comment: @Tommy : actually i want to mean same what you have written.but i know mine explanation is poor. sorry for that. Thanks.

Comment: @BappiDatta : right now i prefer crystal report execute the sp directly, it will more efficient in implementation, and still easy to track. thanks

Comment: Stored procedures and "normal" SQL queries are handled exactly the same way in SQL Server - there's **no** speed advantage for a stored procedure - it's not *pre-compiled* in the database as many pundits keep claiming - that's just not true.

Answer (score 0):

As Hardcore programmer I personally prefer to work with code especially when working with ASP.net. I tell you why:

-**Wizards**: I hate wizards, just going through different steps, the pain of updating a stored procedure etc..

-**Flexibilty**: Code is always the king, I mean just compare command line vs GUI. You are never limited with code.

-**Bugs**: I have seen bugs where calling stored procedure from rpt would not work when the sp returns a temp table, or result were dynamic. Only got it to work with code

Now to answer your question about performance it is definetly faster by code.

**Example**

Bind result to reportviewer (sorry I used reportviewer but you get the point

```
DataTable dt = GetSPResult();
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
```